# Get profile photo to Android contact manager for non-friend contact from Facebook

Tags: photos, facebook

I would like to know if is possible import a Facebook profile photo to contact manager for contacts which **I don't have in my friend list** on Facebook.

For example:

- In Android, I have this contact: "John Smith".
- On Facebook, there also exists some John Smith, but I don't have a John Smith in my friends list on Facebook.
- I would like add his photo from Facebook to the contact manager in Android.

Answer (score 2):

You can manually download the photo and  in your contact manager click the placeholder for photo and chose that File.

As far as automatically importing, your phone can't figure out which "John Smith" is the "John Smith" you want from the list of "John Smiths". The default contact manager can't do this.